Git LFS push doesn't show anything in the GitHub repo after successful push?
I just spent the past 5 hours uploading 20 GB of data to git LFS (large JSON and XML files of texts, like project gutenberg). I ran these commands essentially:
cd existing-github-repo
rm -rf .git # start over
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git
git lfs track *.json # large json files
git lfs track *.xml # large xml files
git add .
git commit -am 'save'
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main -f # force because we had old stuff at that github location

However, after git push, these were my logs:
$ git push -u origin main -f
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.B | 1.3 MB/s
Uploading LFS objects:  32% (27197/85995), 11 GB | 1.2 MB/s
Uploading LFS objects:  42% (36397/85995), 14 GB | 1.2 MB/s
Uploading LFS objects:  42% (36398/85995), 14 GB | 1.2 MB/s
# ... a few more of these ...
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (85995/85995), 22 GB | 1.1 MB/s, done.

Then it was done, no other logs. I visited my GitHub repo and the old content is still there, I don't see anything new. It has been at least an hour since I ran git push.
What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?
I didn't get any error messages saying files were too big, because the big files I put into Git LFS. But nothing is showing up in my repo. How do I get the content onto GitHub?
I've used LFS in the past with great success, but for some reason now it's not working.
Now I'm trying a 3rd time, and here's the status:
$ git push -u origin main -f
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (85995/85995), 22 GB | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 662280, done.
Counting objects: 100% (662280/662280), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (400509/400509), done.
Writing objects:  17% (114399/662280), 894.64 MiB | 1.32 MiB/s

